# Rails: render_to_string without escaping HTML chars (i.e. < and >)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, escaping, pandoc

I need to export strings in Markdown format (that lie in a database) to MS Word Docx format. I decided to use [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) for this.

I have registered a new MIME type `docx`, so I can do stuff like this in a `show.docx.erb` file:

```
# <%= @boilerplate.title %>

## <%= @boilerplate.class.human_attribute_name :intro %>
<%= @boilerplate.intro %>

## <%= @boilerplate.class.human_attribute_name :outro %>
<%= @boilerplate.outro %>
```

Then I do `PandocRuby.convert render_to_string(options), to: :docx`. This creates a nice Word document.

But it has a problem: it escapes HTML chars like `<` and `>`, so when I have e.g. HTML code blocks in the source, their brackets are escaped like `&lt;`.

I need to get an unescaped string from `render_to_string(options)`. Is this possible?

Related issue: https://github.com/alphabetum/pandoc-ruby/issues/14

Comment: Does <%= raw @boilerplate.into %> changes anything?

Comment: I am posting it as an answer then.

Answer (score 1):

Try `<%= raw @boilerplate.into %>` instead.